# Mailgun how to make Cc and Bcc optional php

Tags: php, mailgun

I've been using mailgun for a while and I've always wondered how to make a cc/bcc optional (so if the user wants to Cc themselves it would populate and if not it wouldn't populate).

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array( 
'from' => 'postmaster@example.com', 
'to' =>'to@example.com', 
'cc' => 'MAKE THIS OPTIONAL', 
'h:Reply-To' => 'reply@example.com', 
'subject' => 'Subject, 
'html' => '<!doctype html>....'
```

Comment: You just said the answer. It's a basic if else statement or ternary operator if you like

Comment: Indeed, but I can't submit an empty value for cc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much more simplest way is next.

If you have filled `'cc'` or `'bcc'`, for example, in `$_POST` or `$_GET`:

```
$default_array = [
'from' => 'postmaster@example.com', 
'to' =>'to@example.com', 
'h:Reply-To' => 'reply@example.com', 
'subject' => 'Subject, 
'html' => '<!doctype html>....
];

if (!empty($_POST['cc']) && isset($_POST['cc'])) $default_array['cc'] = $_POST['cc'];
// the same with 'bcc' and others

$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, $default_array);
```